# Tag synonym request: diskonkey -> usb-flash-drive

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

Can someone with tag synonym rights in [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive) consider implementing [diskonkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diskonkey) as a synonym?  There was a [new question in the tag](https://superuser.com/q/1720545/1210833) a few minutes ago, and I had to look up what a "Disk on Key" was (even though it's fairly obvious from the context).  It's possible that I heard that term used in the early, early days, but if so, I'd forgotten all about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed. [diskonkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diskonkey) is somewhat useless and unclear compared to your other tag.

I have merged and synonymised the tags.

Only 6 questions had the tag [diskonkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diskonkey) so it's no big loss.